# Как вытащить пустые данные из квадратных скобок в SQL в python?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, sqlite

Мне нужно чтобы, при отсутствии записей в БД, выводилось сообщение Ваша корзина пуста, но это значение не срабатывает, долго не мог понять почему, потом выяснил, условие else не выполняется в чат боте, через print выяснил, при отсутствии записей выдает [], поэтому выполняется улове IF. В общем и целом, как избавиться от скобок? И доп вопрос. Как сделать так, чтобы все записи отображались одним сообщением, а не каждая запись - 1 сообщение.

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text='basket')
async def basketprint(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    await call.answer()
    username = call.message.chat.username
    user_id = call.message.chat.id
    db = sqlite3.connect('FVS.db')
    cur = db.cursor()
    bskt = cur.execute(f"SELECT product, much, many  FROM `basket` WHERE 
    `user_id`='{user_id}'")
    mouse = cur.fetchall()

    if mouse is not None:
        for product, much, many in mouse:
            await call.message.answer(f"<b>Ваша Корзина:</b>\n"
                                      f"<b>{product}</b>, <b>x{much}</b>,<b>{many}руб</b>")

        db.commit()
        db.close()
        print(mouse)
    else:
        await call.message.answer("Ваша корзина пуста")
```

Comment: Используйте len(mouse)

Comment: Не нужно на `None` проверять вообще, нужно так: `if mouse:` и всё, это пройдёт проверку, если в `mouse` не пустой список.

Comment: А чтобы все записи одним сообщением - сначала сформируйте полный текст в цикле, а потом посылайте его один раз вне цикла.

Comment: if mouse не сработал... тоже самое квадратные скобки появляются... в том то и дело, что не пустой список работает нормально, а на пустые записи появляются скобки, из-за них все равно срабатывает условие not None. Не совсем понимаю, как сформировать полный текст, какие данные сформировать, подскажите по подробнее про это.